# Photo album and editing?

Tags: ios, objective-c

We have to let the user open the photo album, pick an image, and edit it .
So using the picker, i can see all the user albums, than when enter an album i can see the images, than, when tapping an image, i get the delegate .

1. Why i don't see the check sign when choosing an image ? its unclear that you actually pick it. can you also pick more than one, or is it still disabled ?
2. I can't edit the selected image, after i pick it, i got the delegate called, but i don't have the editing button anywhere .

> ```
>  UIImagePickerController *pickerLibrary = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
>         pickerLibrary.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
>         pickerLibrary.delegate = self;
>         pickerLibrary.editing=YES;
>
>         [self presentViewController:pickerLibrary animated:YES completion:nil];
>
>
>
>
>
>
> -(void)imagePickerController:
> (UIImagePickerController *)picker
> didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
> {
>     NSString *mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
>
>     if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage])
>     {
>         UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
>         UIImage *imageE = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
>         NSLog(@"%@",image);
>          NSLog(@"%@",imageE);
>
>
>     }
>     else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
>     {
>         // Media is a video
>     }
>
>     // Code here to work with media
>     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , answer is this :

```
pickerLibrary.allowsEditing=YES;
```

and not `isEditing`